# get multiple div text python bs4 same class name

Tags: python

I'm having trouble parsing HTML elements with "class"  subject-option using Beautifulsoup.i want get text optipn A,option b like during csv imort

The html code is like this :

```
                        <div  data-option="A"  class=" mt-2  subject-option border-1-lightgray p-2" onclick="checkAns(this)">(A)  बढ़ेगा <span class="status" id="56-A"></span></div>

                        <div id="56-2" data-id="56" data-option="B" data-num="2" data-correct="A" class=" mt-2 subject-option border-1-lightgray p-2" onclick="checkAns(this)">(B) घटेगा <span class="status" id="56-B"></span></div>

                        <div id="56-3" data-id="56" data-option="C" data-num="3" data-correct="A" class=" mt-2 subject-option border-1-lightgray p-2" onclick="checkAns(this)">(C) वही रहेगा <span class="status" id="56-C"></span></div>

                        <div id="56-4" data-id="56" data-option="D" data-num="4" data-correct="A" class=" mt-2 subject-option border-1-lightgray p-2" onclick="checkAns(this)">(D)  इनमें से कोई नहीं <span class="status" id="56-D"></span></div>
                    </div>
question = list.find('pre' , class_="subject-question").text.replace('\n','')
   options_A = list.find('div' , class_="subject-option").text.replace('\n','')
   options_B = list.find('div' , class_="subject-option").text.replace('\n','')
   options_C = list.find('div' , class_="subject-option").text.replace('\n','')
   options_D =list.find('div' , class_="subject-option").text.replace('\n','')
```

Comment: Add your python code also of BeautifulSoup

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your elements and iterate over `ResultSet`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<div  data-option="A"  class=" mt-2  subject-option border-1-lightgray p-2" onclick="checkAns(this)">(A)  बढ़ेगा <span class="status" id="56-A"></span></div>
<div id="56-2" data-id="56" data-option="B" data-num="2" data-correct="A" class=" mt-2 subject-option border-1-lightgray p-2" onclick="checkAns(this)">(B) घटेगा <span class="status" id="56-B"></span></div>
<div id="56-3" data-id="56" data-option="C" data-num="3" data-correct="A" class=" mt-2 subject-option border-1-lightgray p-2" onclick="checkAns(this)">(C) वही रहेगा <span class="status" id="56-C"></span></div>
<div id="56-4" data-id="56" data-option="D" data-num="4" data-correct="A" class=" mt-2 subject-option border-1-lightgray p-2" onclick="checkAns(this)">(D)  इनमें से कोई नहीं <span class="status" id="56-D"></span></div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for e in soup.select('div.subject-option'):
    print(e.text)
```

###### Output

```
(A)  बढ़ेगा 
(B) घटेगा 
(C) वही रहेगा 
(D)  इनमें से कोई नहीं
```